# recognize person by its voice using tensor flow and ML kit

Tags: android, tensorflow, voice-recognition, firebase-mlkit

I want to know the feasibility of an android app which I am going to build for my College project.
The App, which I am trying to build is for attendance on the class through voice recognition or face detection.
For this, I suppose to first collect the data set for all the student of the class and then train it.
so, Is it feasible to build such an app and how to approach this?
I am new in Tensor flow and ML and also searched about this on the internet but unsuccessful to find anything so please help me come out from this. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you read about [Face Detecion on ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces)?

Comment: Yes @Rosário Pereira Fernandes, but how to get data and train the data for 60-70 student in a class and then classify all.

Comment: You might want to use a [custom model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models)

Comment: for face recognition there are many, but for speaker recognition the only viable option as far as i know is https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to train and use a custom model for this.
ML Kit offers face detection but does not offer face recognition or voice recognition at the moment. So you will have to collect data and train a model yourself. You can look at the quickstart samples for [iOS](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/mlkit) and [Android](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) on GitHub and learn about [using mobile-optimized custom models](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models) in your app.